# Асинхронное использование Selenium в телеграм боте aiogram3.x python

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, selenium, aiogram-3.x

Пишу Бота, который будет регестрировать пользователя на сайте и потом отправлять ему нужные данные (курсы, файлы, ...)

Я написал класс `MoodleProfile` с помощью которого создаю экземпляр `person = MoodleProfile()` внутри хендлера. При запуске бота, с двух аккаунтов, бот сначала парсит данные для одного пользователя, а потом как закончит для другого.

**Как сделать чтобы бот мог параллельно обслуживать несколько пользователей?**

Comment: Пробуйте слениум запускать через asyncio.to_thread

Comment: запускать в потоке(asyncio.to_thread или threading) , или использовать ассинхроный аналог playwright

Comment: @insolor, Спасибо огромное, все получилось благодаря to_thread()